# table with no primary key

Tags: database-design

I have two tables

- doctor (doc_id, Doc_name, Doc_phone)
- Specialization (doc_id, specialization)

a doctor can have zero or many specializations, but I'm not sure what the primary key for Specialization would be.

Comment: `Specialization` table do not need in primary index. It's enough to have unique composite index by all two fields combination in any order. Optimal order is dependent by the queries stream to this table (including the percentage for each separate query type).  In most cases this composite index can be either primary or common unique - it doesn't matter. But if you want to reference to specialization combinations (not use for joining), I'd recommend to use synthetic (autoincrement) primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can a Specialization exist without a Doctor?  I suspect it can, in which case you need a third table, to "master" these Specializations and your Doctor/Specialization becomes a Weak Entity joining those two:

```
select * from doctor ; 

+----+-----------------+ 
| id | name            | 
+----+-----------------+ 
|  1 | Fred Flintstone |  They retrained :-) 
|  2 | Barney Rubble   | 
+----+-----------------+ 

select * from specialization ; 

+----+------------+
| id | name       | 
+----+------------+
| 33 | Neurology  | 
| 44 | Psychiatry |
| 55 | Radiology  |
+----+------------+

select * from doctor_specialization ; 

+--------+---------+
| doc_id | spec_id | 
+--------+---------+
|      1 |      33 |
|      2 |      55 | 
+--------+---------+
```

Your Primary Key for doctor_specialization is the *entire record* - you can't have a record that doesn't have both values present, nor can you have duplicates of their combination. 
Further, each field has a Foreign Key back to its [own] parent table.

```
primary key ( doc_id, spec_id )
foreign key ( doc_id ) references doctor ( id ) 
foreign key ( spec_id ) references specialization (id )
```

If you needed to find a doctor with a given Specialization, you might consider a Covering Index going back the other way:

```
create index i_ds_spec 
on doctor_specialization ( spec_id, doc_id ) ;
```

Comment: +1 for Fred Flintstone doing psychiatry! :-)

Comment: But he's not ...   Fred's more of a hands-on guy, which is why he opted for Neurology - Brain Surgeon!

Answer (score 0):

A primary key can be compound (consist of multiple columns), and even cover the entire table (be all of the table’s columns).

In your case, (doc_id, specialization) is the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

The key for this should be DOC_ID & SPECIALIZATION (ID).

This should be able to identify records for this table uniquely.  Read this as "***For every doctor there is a specialization and for every specialization there is a doctor in this table***"